# Using LIKE within CASE in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, sql-like

I would like to select the records that contain the content of the `@selctDescription` parameter but only when `@selctDescription`  is not empty.

I have the following, which does not work:

```
(t.[description] LIKE 
  (
  CASE 
  WHEN @selctDescription = '' THEN t.[description] 
  ELSE ('%' @selctDescription '%') 
  END
  )
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE 
  ((@selctDescription IS NULL OR @selctDescription = '') 
   OR
   (t.[description] LIKE '%' + @selctDescription +'%'))
```

Comment: So remove `@selctDescription IS NULL`, even you are not using NULL today it much safe to consider this, I would say IsNullOrEmpty is common pattern for such case so I would suggest leave IS NULL condition as well

Comment: @CiccioMiami: we did not know that ;-) Just remove that part then

Answer (score 2):

```
@selctDescription = '' OR t.[description] LIKE '%' + @selctDescription + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is equivalent to:

```
t.[description]  LIKE  '%' + @selctDescription + '%'
```

Your description on the other hand, suggests you want this:

```
@selctDescription <> ''
AND t.[description]  LIKE  '%' + @selctDescription + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts for you...

Where you have `'%' @selctDescription '%'`, you just need `+` between the strings to concatenate them.  Your code will then work as is.

- `'%' + @selctDescription + '%'`

Also, it's useful to note that you don't even need the `CASE` statement, as when the parameter is blank, you get `'%%'`, which will still match everything.

This is useful to know because at present you have table fields on both sides of the `LIKE` statement.  This will really hurt the optimiser.  If I were to use CASE I'd be more tempted to stick to...

```
t.[description] LIKE (CASE WHEN @selctDescription = '' THEN '%' ELSE ('%' + @selctDescription + '%') END)
```

This has the benefit that the result of the CASE statement can be performed once, as a scalar value, prior to execution of the query.  As opposed to being recalculated ever row.

And that said, it then becomes functionally identical to...

```
t.[description] LIKE ('%' + @selctDescription + '%')
```

Comment: t.[description] LIKE (CASE WHEN '@selctDescription' = '' THEN '%' ELSE ('%' + '@selctDescription' + '%') END), is it possible to use this expression when I have '=' instead of like?

Comment: You don't want `'` around your variable names.  But other than that, yes, you can use this pattern for an `=` operation too...  `table.x = (CASE WHEN @variable = '' THEN 'Something Special' ELSE @variable END)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first line and comments, you need to make the following select:

```
Select * from table
  where field <> ''
  and field like '%' + @selctDescription + '%'
```

But you must put the correct *table* and *field* and @selctDesciption must be text (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar, ...).